# WooCommerce custom shipping costs for min required subtotal with tax calculations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tax, shipping-method

I have set some Shipping methods with taxable option enabled in WooCommerce. I use this code to set up different shipping cost if spend over X amount:

```
// Extra discount on shipping for orders of values of above 150 or 100.
function custom_adjust_shipping_rate( $rates ) {
    $cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;

    // Check if the subtotal is greater than value specified
    if ( $cart_subtotal >= 29.99 ) {

        // Loop through each shipping rate
        foreach ( $rates as $rate ) {

            // Store the previous cost in $cost
            $cost = $rate->cost;

            // Adjust the cost as needed
            // original shipping greater than 6 discount by 5 
            if ( $cost == 7.38 ) {
                // discount rate by 5
                $rate->cost = $cost - 2.54;
            }
            // Optional discount for other shipping rates 
            if ( $cost == 4.10 ) {
                $rate->cost = $cost - 5;
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_adjust_shipping_rate', 10 );
```

But the problem is the tax calculations. My code doesn't handle taxes.

How can I adjust taxes from custom shipping cost?

How to enable taxes in cost calculations?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable shipping taxes calculations in your code, use the following revisited code instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'adjust_shipping_rates_cost', 10, 2 );
function adjust_shipping_rates_cost( $rates, $package ) {
    $min_subtotal  = 30; // Set min subtotal
    $cart_subtotal = 0; // Initializing
        
    // Loop through cart items to get items total for the current shipping package 
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ) {
        $cart_subtotal += $item['line_subtotal'] + $item['line_subtotal_tax'];
        // $cart_subtotal += $item['line_subtotal']; // Or without taxes
    }

    // Check if the subtotal is greater than specified value
    if ( $cart_subtotal < $min_subtotal ) {
        return $rates; // Exit
    }

    // Loop through shipping rates
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        $has_taxes = false; // Initializing
        $taxes     = array(); // Initializing
        $new_cost = $initial_cost = $rate->cost; // grab initial cost

        if ( $initial_cost == 7.38 ) {
            $new_cost -= 2.54;
        } elseif ( $initial_cost == 4.10 ) {
            $new_cost -= 5;
        }
        $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $new_cost; // Set new rate cost

        // Loop through taxes array (change taxes rate cost if enabled)
        foreach ($rate->taxes as $key => $tax){
            if( $tax > 0 ){
                // Get the tax rate conversion
                $tax_rate    = $tax / $initial_cost;

                // Set the new tax cost in the array
                $taxes[$key] = $new_cost * $tax_rate;
                $has_taxes   = true; // Enabling tax changes
            }
        }
        // set array of shipping tax cost
        if( $has_taxes ) {
            $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Don't forget to empty your cart to refresh shipping cached data.

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work... If I add this code, the price of shipping in orders >30€ are the same

Comment: Ok, I have for example two shipping id:
1) Standard Shipping (id 6), 5,90€ (tax included) for orders <30€, free on orders >=30€.
2) COD (id 5), 9€ (tax included) for orders <30€, 5,90€ (tax included) on orders >=30€.

Where I have to set the shipping rate id? thank you very much

Comment: Hello, Why if I add in $initial_cost a value of 7.384 (and not 7.38) it doesn't work?